# Why compile() runs only when $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation() invoked?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a directive which takes part of its template (set via templateUrl) and moves it into $rootElement (so this part becomes the last child of it). And it's defined like this:

```
.directive(...

    return {
    restrict: "E",
                templateUrl: templUrl,
            controller: "MyCtrl",
            scope: {
            },

            compile: function (element, attrs) {
                return {
                    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
...
                        // move modal's div to the end of $rootElement so all modals will be put one after another INSTEAD OF MAKING A HIERARCHY
                        var modalElement = $("div.modal", iElement);
                        modalElement.appendTo($rootElement);

                        // compile and link the selector's modal
                        $compile(modalElement)(scope);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

In my jasmine test I have to invoke $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation() in order the test to work properly:

```
it("Element must be replaced by the template", function () {
    var linkingFn = $compile("<div ng-app><mydir></mydir></div>");
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();  // DOES NOT WORK WITHOUT IT
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var element = linkingFn(scope);

    // element - is <mydir></mydir>
    var buttonElm = $("div:first-child", element);
    expect(buttonElm).not.toBeUndefined();
    expect(buttonElm.hasClass("form-group")).toBe(true);
});
```

If I comment out verifyNoOutstandingExpectation() directive's postLink function gets invoked after all my expect statements. I don't understand why. Any ideas are welcome!